# Website showing duplicate logos in header in IE8 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rendering

I have checked my CSS and I never specify the logo as a background graphic. There is not logo in the background graphic - just a gray bar, but in IE8 and IE7 the logo is duplicating itself one over the other. Here is the website: www.americaninstrument.com.

I ran a W3 compatibility test and, while there were issues with the javascript analytics code and some links, there was nothing that would affect this logo.

The logo image is called object0.png

Comment: I have searched all of the source code for this line: background-image: url("http://www.americaninstrument.com/images/object0.png") and with background-image: url("images/object0.png") and background-image: url("../images/object0.png") and I get NOT FOUND. None of the 3 style sheets lists object0.png as a background image.

Comment: I found it! It was in a javascript file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First child div of the one with class `wk-shapes`:

```
<div style='background: url("http://www.americaninstrument.com/images/object0.png") no-repeat 15px 37px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
```

has the following inline-style:

```
background-image: url("http://www.americaninstrument.com/images/object0.png")
```